# Multitail configuration:defaultcscheme isn't applied

Tags: tail

Finally i got Multitail to work. The only problem is the Default Colorscheme isn't applied to a file i open with multitail, so have to go to the menu and apply it manually.

My multitail.conf looks like this

```
#test
defaultcscheme:test
colorscheme:test: my test colorscheme
cs_re_s:white,black,bold/blink:([^:]*): SRC
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

in the preconfigured config file http://github.com/avar/linode-etc/blob/master/multitail.conf you have be sure to modify i.e. at scheme:syslog,ssh:/var/log/